# Search for a particular cell in Google Spreadsheets and return the row number

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

For instance, I have a bunch of categories with 1 on each row and each category has 1 or more data on their own column. Given a string, I want to find which category it belongs to.

```
         A    |     B     |     C     |     D
1    CARS     |  Civic    |           |
2    TRUCKS   |  F-150    |  F-650    |  F-750
3    PLANES   |  747      |  F/A-18   |
```

Given `747`, I want to know that it is from row 3 or that it is a plane or that `F-` is a truck.

I've tried using several functions, including `vlookup`, `filter`, `match`, etc, but couldn't get them to work.

Is it possible to do this without scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is in columns A to E (this could be extended), and that the search term is in F1, and the search term must start the string, and that all applicable matches will be returned, try:

`=IF(LEN(F1),FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(IF(REGEXMATCH(B:E&"","^"&F1),ROW(A:A)),ROW(A:A))),)`

Comment: It works, but my search term is larger than the data, so it doesn't match. Is it possible to search for something like `747-8` and find it in `B3`?

Comment: You will need to be prescriptive of the exact conditions that would constitute a match.

Comment: So I would have to create rules for every search term for a match?

Comment: Not so much that, just describe in words what the rules are. Eg F- should match F-150, yet 747-8 should match 747. Should F-250 match F-150? Just have to lay out the rules first I guess, then someone will come up with a formula. (And I suppose, the more "liberal" you are with what constitutes a match, the more chance there will be of false positives.)

Comment: There isn't really any set rules. I'm pasting sets of information from another source and I got tired of categorizing every row manually, so I wanted to have it more or less automatic. This formula already made it much easier, so I guess it's good enough. Another problem is it won't match exact strings containing asterixes.

Comment: Happy to help, but might need to see a copy of your ss (sensitive data removed) to get a better idea of your workflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61454/discussion-between-gavsiu-and-adaml).